# Как скопировать из поля в другое поле той же строки в dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, nan

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В третьем столбце видно, как дата перескочила из 4 столбца, ее надо перенести в четвертый столбец, а потом третий удалить.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приводите исходные данные хотя бы частично. как по-вашему мы должны работать с вашим датафреймом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы делал это так:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=[0], parse_dates=["4"], dayfirst=True)
dt = pd.to_datetime(df.pop("3"), errors= 'coerce')
df.loc[dt.notna(), "4"] = dt
```

---

результат:

```
In [49]: df
Out[49]:
        0  1    2          4
0    7729  2  129 2017-05-04
1    7732  3  155 2017-05-04
2    5583  2   90 2017-05-04
3    7756  1   79 2017-05-04
4    7749  2   76 2017-05-04
5    7745  1   45 2017-05-04
6    5579  1   43 2017-05-04
..    ... ..  ...        ...
93   5579  1   43 2017-05-09
94   5581  1   43 2017-05-09
95   7740  2   90 2017-05-10
96   7755  1  154 2017-10-05
97   5587  1   43 2017-05-10
98  51059  4  153 2017-05-10
99   5579  2   86 2017-05-10

[100 rows x 4 columns]

In [50]: df.dtypes
Out[50]:
0             int64
1             int64
2             int64
4    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Допустим, есть датафрейм `df`:

```
    1  2                   3                   4
0  10  a                   1  09.11.2019 0:00:00
1  20  a                   2  09.11.2019 0:00:00
2  30  a  09.11.2019 0:00:00                 NaN
3  40  a                   4  09.11.2019 0:00:00
4  50  a  09.11.2019 0:00:00                 NaN
5  60  a                   6  09.11.2019 0:00:00
```

Тога, чтобы получить желаемый вами результат сразу для всего датафрейма, можно сделать так:

```
df.loc[~df['3'].str.isdigit(), '4'] = df['3']
df.drop(['3'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

что даст нам:

```
    1  2                   4
0  10  a  09.11.2019 0:00:00
1  20  a  09.11.2019 0:00:00
2  30  a  09.11.2019 0:00:00
3  40  a  09.11.2019 0:00:00
4  50  a  09.11.2019 0:00:00
5  60  a  09.11.2019 0:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно:

```
df3.iloc[10553,4] = df3.iloc[10553, 3]
df3.iloc[10553, 3] = float('nan')
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j5OVa6yz8r3RlOqZLFDX2eaSYKQQ6Rsv/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Можно заполнить nan предыдущим значением в строке

```
df.ffill(axis=1).drop(columns='3')

   0   1  2                   4
0  0  10  a  09.11.2019 0:00:00
1  1  20  a  09.11.2019 0:00:00
2  2  30  a  09.11.2019 0:00:00
3  3  40  a  09.11.2019 0:00:00
4  4  50  a  09.11.2019 0:00:00
5  5  60  a  09.11.2019 0:00:00
```